# How to change content with HREF Click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Hello Stackers,**

I'm having another problem now, and this time it is one, where I'm not even knowing how to start the code. I Have 3 links, and four divs. One DIV is the default, and the others are when clicking on the link. Only, I Want it to hide and show the div with jQuery, which I'm not that good at.

I Know this won't work with anchors, or does it?

```
<a href="#div1">SHOW DIV1</a>
<a href="#div2">SHOW DIV2</a>
<a href="#div3">SHOW DIV3</a>

<div id="default">Default Content</div>
<div id="1">DIV 1 Content</div>
<div id="2">DIV 2 Content</div>
<div id="3">DIV 3 Content</div>
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: *`"jQuery, which I'm not that good at"`* does not mean other have to code instead of you. Please next time show some effort and share with us your best try!

Comment: I Did, which was that bad that I deleted it. Still thanks for your tip.

Comment: You're welcome. P.S: [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 $().ready(function(){   
    $('div').not('#default').hide(); // hide all divs except for 'default' on page load     
    $('a').click(function(e) // bind a click event on the anchor tags
    {
      $('div').not('#default').hide();; // hide all divs except for 'default'
      e.preventDefault(); 
      var container = $(this).attr('href').replace('#div',''); // find the corresponding div to show using the 'href' attribute 
      $("#" + container).show(); // show that div
    });
  });
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/s8131f7e/1/

Comment: Hello. First of all, thanks for your support. I've taken a while to look at your code, and it seems to be working, for a part. It does hide a div when I click, however the new one does not appear. I wanted to be sure that I'm not doing anything wrong, so I'm having a small question. The divs should be called "1", "2" and so on right?

Comment: You have to make sure that the new href should have id = '#div[divid]". as long you that in place, it would work fine.